# Need pattern for specific string in PHP

Tags: php, regex

How can I code a function in PHP to check input string with allowed pattern? my pattern is like this:

**1-1341498217**

First section is one digit integer from 0 to 9 and the second section after dash is 10 digits positive integer number.

Thanks.

Comment: I am a little bit confused. how can I make sure about provided solutions? I did some test but I think I've found malfunctioning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this `preg_match("/^\d-[1-9]\d{9}$/", $string)`

Answer (score 2):

```
preg_match("/\d-\d{10}/", $string);
```

?

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_match("/^\d-[1-9]{10}$/", $string)
                 //^--------------for positive digits
```